# Boto3- multiple cron jobs for single lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

Could someone please educate me if it is feasible to apply conditions in a lambda function based on the cloudwatch cron jobs. Something like this :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if cronjob1:
       print("Yes")
    elif cronjon2:
       print("No")
```

BR\
Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your CloudWatch Events to send a json object to the lambda function when they invoke it.

When you're adding a lambda function as a target of an even, click **Configure Input** -> **Constant (JSON text)** -> then enter something like `{"eventName":"cronjob1"}`

Now you can get this value from an even like this: `event['eventName']`